# the meaning of 'shuffle shoulder'

Tags: word-meaning

> Shub was a pale, ***shuffle-shouldered*** man with little puzzled eyes and a
>   huge spread of shapeless nose.
>
> -[The Apprenticeship of Duddy Kravitz](https://books.google.ru/books?id=XNVuITZr9EMC&pg=PA152&dq=Shub+was+a+pale,+shuffle-shouldered+man+with+little+puzzled+eyes+and+a+huge+spread+of+shapeless+nose.&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi97JfsosnTAhUGiiwKHToSCuUQ6AEIIzAA#v=onepage&q=Shub%20was%20a%20pale%2C%20shuffle-shouldered%20man%20with%20little%20puzzled%20eyes%20and%20a%20huge%20spread%20of%20shapeless%20nose.&f=false) by Mordecai Richler -

What kind of shoulder is that?

Comment: i don't think that it has any well-defined meaning. It is probably not very flattering.

Comment: I'm looking forward to a reliable enlightening  answer. I'd have understood "shoulder-shuffling" but  I can't get through  "shuffle-shouldered".  Could it be shoulders cut to shuffle nicely / to make a good shuffle? I've found the sentence [in context](http://bit.ly/2prqm09), so we know Shub is a boxer, that explains the nose, but how does it help for the shoulders?

Comment: @Laure: it's not a shuffle-shouldered jacket but a shuffle-shouldered man.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo A jacket? What makes you think I'd thought Shub was a  jacket. I was talking about a man...it's clear Shub is a man.

Comment: @Laure: the verb "cut" is what made me think that.

Comment: @Laure: I didn't think you thought Shub *was* a jacket, but that you were imagining him in a jacket.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo *cut: "well-developed and highly defined musculature"

Comment: @Laure:  "cut to shuffle nicely" didn't send me in that direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**shuffle-shouldered** is not a collocation, and so we can only make educated guesses at what it might mean.

He could be a man whose shoulders swing nonchalantly as he walks. I believe this has been the boxer's iconic walk in American cinema.

That would be in keeping with the most common meaning of **shuffle** in the context of bodily posture and movement.